# Meteor/Meteorite - I have a PDF file in a folder that I want users to be able to download

Tags: node.js, pdf, download, meteor, meteorite

What is the simplest way to accomplish this? I have looked at CollectionFS but honestly it seems way to complicated for a task that is much simpler in other frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the router package to allow you to store the file wherever you want (outside your project per exemple).

Then with the router you just specify a route '/documents/:filename'
and you use "fs" package to read file and send deliver it to the client. :

Have a look at my code : https://github.com/Rebolon/meteor-tuto-routerAndFileDownload/blob/master/tuto-routerAndImage.js
it's quite simple and it allows you to store file where ever you want (even on Cloud ;-), not only in your meteor project

Comment: if it solve your problem, thanks to vote for the right answer of your question ;-)

Comment: @Rebolon This is pretty good, and your answer helped inspire a solution to a related problem. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can just put the file in the `public` folder.

the file: `./public/pdfs/mydoc.pdf`

can be accessed as: `https://www.example.com/pdfs/mydoc.pdf`